# Easiest way to convert number stored as text to number in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I trying to convert this text into numbers:

[image]

I have tried different formulas but Excel is not recognizing the format. 
However, using the code below it converts only the first three numbers and removes the rest.

```
Sub ConvertTextNumberToNumber()
For Each WS In Sheets
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In WS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If IsNumeric(r) Then r.Value = Val(r.Value)
    Next r
Next WS
End Sub
```

The result looks like this

[image]

Does anyone have an ease fix for this without removing any numbers?

Comment: Thank you R3uK !!! It works perfect!

Comment: Something does not seem to be right, because if the numbers were really stored as text, then this line would have failed: `If IsNumeric(r) Then r.Value = Val(r.Value)`. Therefore, it seems that the real issue is not that the values in the cells were text but something to do with the format of the cell, probably formatted as text.

Comment: What decimal and thousands separators uses your machine?

Comment: @OlaOkland, remember to select an answer if someone had posted one which you used and worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing this answer in relation with OP statement:

> I have tried different formulas but Excel is not recognizing the
>   format.

There is no need to use VBA for that operation.

Use this formula if your decimal character is a period [.]

```
=SUM( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( B2, " ", "" ), ",", "." ) )
```

Or this one if your decimal character is a colon [,]

```
=SUM( SUBSTITUTE( B2, " ", "" ) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

**Easiest way to convert a number stored as text, is to multiply it by `1`**, 
So try this `If IsNumeric(r) Then r.Value = (r.Value)*1`

Or you can copy paste with a multiplication by 1 and this works too! ;)

```
Sub ConvertTextNumberToNumber()
For Each WS In Sheets
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In WS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If IsNumeric(r) Then r.Value = (r.Value)*1
        ''Or test the values in the next column on the right
        'If IsNumeric(r) Then r.Offset(0,1).Value = (r.Value)*1
    Next r
Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I would test your data by multiplying the text value in the next cell 1.  Example: in Cell B1, try the formula: =A1 * 1.

Comment: `If IsNumeric(r) Then r.Offset(0,1).Value = (r.Value)*1` normally, you'd have to post a question and not ask one in comments! ;)

Comment: I wasn't asking a question in the comments. I can confirming that what you said was correct. And to test this would work correctly you can test in a formula adjacent to the data you want to convert before coding any VBA. ;)

Comment: @PaulG : My bad, I didn't get that! ;) I edited my answer to reflect your suggestion! ;)

Comment: This does not work for me on Excel 2013, Windows 7. Stays as number stored as text.

Comment: @Kos : Check the format of your cells, I'll be they are in text ;) Or add `r.NumberFormat = "# ##0.00"` (inside the numeric test)

Answer (score 0):

Provided your data is always using a "space" as a thousand separator and a "comma" as a decimal point, you can use the following(Modified from your original script).

```
Sub ConvertTextNumberToNumber()
    For Each WS In Sheets
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each r In WS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

            'For testing purposes I like to see the cell which is selected
            r.Select
            'Setting the Cell Number Format
            'for more or less decimals just add/remove 0 after the . 
            r.NumberFormat = "0.00"
            'Assigning the Cell value to a String
            String1 = r.Value
            'Replacing the spaces with no space
            String1 = Replace(String1, " ", "")
            'Replacing the comma with a point
            String1 = Replace(String1, ",", ".")
            'Putting the new value into the cell
            r.Value = String1
        Next r
    Next WS
End Sub
```